# How to switch to another running application using its process id in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, pid

How can I switch to another running application in Windows 7 and C++ when I know its process id?

I only have the process id. There might be several applications with the same name so using the window title does not work. I also do not have a reliable HWND to use.

I want the application to be active, visible and ready for input just as if I switched to it using alt-tab.

Comment: have you tried the obvious `c++ windows switch to application` search?

Comment: Just enumerate all top level windows until you find one belonging to the PID with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style set. Bring that window to the front of the z-order and give it input focus.

Comment: That does not really work reliably because not every Application has the WS_EX_APPWINDOW style set.

Comment: If the app appears on the task bar or in the task-switch window it has the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style. If not choose a criteria that gets you as close as possible.

Comment: Out of 6 Apps I tried that are on the taskbar only 1 had the WS_EX_APPWINDOW style set. And simply choosing criterias that might not work reliably sounds sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
HWND hNewWindow = FindWindow(...); // get window handle by title etc.
if (hNewWindow)
{
    DWORD hCurrentWindowThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWndCurrentWindow, NULL );
    DWORD hNewWindowThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId( hNewWindow, NULL);
    AttachThreadInput( hCurrentWindowThread, hNewWindowThread, TRUE );
    SetForegroundWindow(hNewWindow);
    AttachThreadInput( hCurrentWindowThread, hNewWindowThread, FALSE );
}
```

SetForegroundWindow is doing the magic you want here. It has limitations outlined here [SetforegroundWindow() API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Solution from [here.](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/launching-apps-in-the-foreground/184405755)

Comment: I cannot use FindWindow because it uses the window title and that, unlike the process id, is not unique.

Comment: Note that this may find an invisible window or some other window that is not intended to be interactive.